# Function that takes form data and submits it (without hitting submit button)?

Tags: jquery, ajax

is it possible to make a function that takes form data and executes a php file on the spot without having to leave the page? Thanks :))

Comment: What event should submit the data? Do you want to submit on every keypress, when a certain field is filled, as soon as the form validates correctly, etc?

Comment: This should help you doing what you want: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: Yes, I made a  `function alertData() {
alert("Something here"); 
}    ` where I then tried to insert the same php which I use for the form submit - but then I remembered that I have to submit the data first somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without an actual submit, but still with a buttonclick you could do it like this:

html:

```
<form>

  <input type="text" id="name"></input>
  <input type="text" id="age"></input>

  <input id="myButton" type="button"></input>

</form>
```

javascript:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  var data = {
    name: $('#name').val();
    age: $('#age').val();
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.mydomain.com/myphpfile.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(){
      alert('done...');
    }
  });
});
```

more info on ajax submitting with jquery:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

```
function executeFormSubmit(formSelector,callback/*optional*/){
    var form = $(formSelector),
        method = form.attr('method') || 'get',
        action = form.attr('action') || '',
        query = form.serialize(),
        separator = action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&';
    $.ajax({
        url : action + separator + query,
        method : method,
        success : function(){
            typeof callback == 'function' && callback.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    });
}
```